# Replicating Git Notes between 2 central git servers

Tags: git, gerrit

I want to transfer ALL git notes refs (`refs/notes/*`) from one central git repository to another.

Assuming the git central servers `A` and `B`, and I want to replicate git notes from `A` to `B`.

I tried to use options like:

- `git push remoteB refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*; git push --mirror` (this option works, but it is deleting additional refs, for example branches, that do not exist in `A`);
- `git push --all` (this option does not keep git notes in sync, but works well in keeping `refs/heads` in sync) in a post-commit git hook.

---

```
[git@hdqpdqaapp5 modeln50.git]$ GIT_TRACE=1 git push 
source +refs/notes/*:refs/notes/* 
trace: built-in: git 'push' 'source' '+refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*' 
trace: run_command: 'ssh' '-p' '8081' 'hdqpdsource1.modeln.com' 'git-receive-pack '\''/modeln56.git'\'''
```

It is picking up the remote name correctly but, the project name is wrong (`modeln56`), also, the command just hangs without any output.

Comment: As in http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git.user/4524, could you run `git push` with the `GIT_TRACE`
environment variable set to `1` and see what refspecs are really passed to `git send-pack`? (note to self: gerrit review notes: https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/refs-notes-review.html)

Comment: hi von ... thnaks for your comment ... here is the output :[git@hdqpdqaapp5 modeln50.git]$ GIT_TRACE=1 git push source +refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
trace: built-in: git 'push' 'source' '+refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' '-p' '8081' 'hdqpdsource1.modeln.com' 'git-receive-pack '\''/modeln56.git'\''' it is picking up the remote name correctly but, the project name is wrong (modeln56), also, the command just hangs without any output ...

Comment: Ok, what does `git remote -v` returns (when executed from within your local clone)?

Comment: Here are my remote:                                                             source ssh://hdqpdsource1.modeln.com:8081/home/git/repositories/modeln56.git (fetch)
source  ssh://hdqpdsource1.modeln.com:8081/home/git/repositories/modeln56.git (push)

Comment: Woud a `git push source refs/notes/*:refs/notes/* ; git push --all source` works better?

Comment: You may find my [`git-rnotes`](https://github.com/aspiers/git-config/blob/master/bin/git-rnotes) wrapper script of use or interest.

Answer (score 0):

That should push all you want (notes and heads):

```
git push remoteB 'refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*' 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```

You can push also tags by adding the refspec `'refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'`.

You can set the config `remote.remoteB.push` if you want to avoid typing the list of refspecs.